# Elegant way to replace the tag on a sequence of bs4 soup tags and wrap them all in another tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html string like so:

```
test = """<body>
    <h1>A header</h1>
    <p> Just a normal paragraph <b>before</b> </p>
    <p>• test element</p>
    <p>• test element2</p>
    <p> Following <i>stuff</i></p>

    </body>
    """
```

This user has explicitly included the `u'\u2022'` bullet character instead of using a list. I would like to get the following converted html

```
<body>
    <h1>A header</h1>
    <p> Just a normal paragraph <b>before</b> </p>
    <ul>
    <li>test element</li>
    <li>test element2</li>
    </ul>
    <p> Following <i>stuff</i></p>

</body>
```

What is the most elegant way to approach this? I can identify then these bulleted items occur from a simple .find on the tag string. I can remove the bullets and wrap them in `<li>` tags. But I don't know how to iterate through the soup and then wrap all the bullets into a single `<ul>` tag. If I could iterate through the soup like a normal list and create a modified list with new elements I could do something like this pseudo-code:

```
new_soup = []
for tag in soup:
   if has_bullet(tag):
       #  start storing tags
       bullets.append(tag)
   else:
       if bullets: # if we have some bullets to dump
           new_soup.append(ul_tag_start)
           new_soup.extend(modify_text(bullets))
           new_soup.append(ul_tag_end)
       new_soup.append(tag)
       # clear bullets list
       bullets = []
```

but I don't know to write a new soup element by element, and I wonder if there's a better way using bs4's various insert, insert_before, insert_after, etc. methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
import bs4, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
test = """<h1>A header</h1><p> Just a normal paragraph <b>before</b> </p><p>• test element</p><p>• test element2<b>something else</b></p><p> Following <i>stuff</i></p>"""
def form_ul(d):
   return soup('<ul>{}</ul>'.format('\n'.join(f'<li>{i}</li>' for i in d)), 'html.parser').ul

def to_ul(d):
   c,l = [],[]
   for i in d.contents:
      if isinstance(i, bs4.NavigableString):
         c.append(i)
      else:
         if str(i.get_text(strip=True)).startswith(u'\u2022'):
            l.append('\n'.join(j.replace(u'\u2022 ', '') if isinstance(j, bs4.NavigableString) else str(j) for j in i.contents))
         else:
            if l:
               c.append(form_ul(l))
               l = []
            to_ul(i)
            c.append(i)
   if l:
      c.append(form_ul(l))
   d.contents = [j for j in c if not re.findall('^\n+$', str(j))]

html = soup(test, 'html.parser')
to_ul(html)
print(soup.prettify(html))
```

Output:

```html
<h1>
 A header
</h1>
<p>
 Just a normal paragraph
 <b>
  before
 </b>
</p>
<ul>
 <li>
  test element
 </li>
 <li>
  test element2
  <b>
   something else
  </b>
 </li>
</ul><p>
 Following
 <i>
  stuff
 </i>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works for the example above but doesn't work for my actual use case, in which that first linking element might be something like `• test <b>element</b>` rather than just `• test element`. In other words, I need to preserve other tags within that line if present. Is the most correct way to do this to do `l.append(str(i))` rather than `l.append(t)`? Edit: Just realized that doesn't quite work as it keeps the `<p>` tags.

Comment: This works: `l.append(str(i).replace('<p>','').replace('</p>', ''))```, but seems pretty hacky. However, trying to do an unwrap isn't working for me. Better ideas?

Comment: @gammapoint Please see my recent edit, as I added a solution that will preserve all child HTML of any element with `•`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm going to mark this as correct because it seems like it works for these test cases. However, outside of this minimal working example the behavior of this is pretty odd for me. For example, working one way if I operate on my html as originally found in my source versus writing the html to file and re-reading with bs4. I don't yet understand this divergence in behavior, but your code certainly gives me a good place to start. Also, I noticed that sometimes the `.replace(u'\u2022', '') doesn't work for me and I need to do a regex replace instead.

Comment: @gammapoint The encodings and format could play a role those sporadic results you are getting. I just updated the post to make sure that trailing text after a list block triggers the creation of a `ul`

Comment: When writing to file, I was writing the html as  `f.write(str(soup.prettify()))`. Perhaps that prettification (which as I understand writes newlines) is the reason that this example code works and my actual problem doesn't (unless I prettify first). Unfortunately, when I prettify the text and re-read it my other tests break. Any thoughts on that? Would differing format and newlines in the example test change the result?

Comment: @gammapoint Yes, it could, but it is a bit hard to say. Does my most recent edit work for you?

Comment: @gammapoint Perhaps the encoding of the bullet point is changed. Can you print out `l` before every `c.append(form_ul(l))`?

Comment: The whitespace does seem to make a difference. In using your most recent edit, if I try to process the string: `test = """
<h1>A header</h1><p> Just a normal paragraph <b>before</b> </p><p>• test element</p><p>• test element2<b>something else</b></p><p> Following <i>stuff</i></p>
"""` (same string but with no newlines) I get `<h1>A header</h1><p> Just a normal paragraph <b>before</b> </p><ul><li>test element</li></ul><p> Following <i>stuff</i></p>`. In other words, it misses one of the bullets.

Comment: @gammapoint Please see my recent edit, it works now on your latest input sample. It seems that `soup.destruct` was also removing certain proceeding HTML elements after the detection of a bullet.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Ajax. It does seem to work on the latest input sample. It also works on the first input sample, but now there's a bunch of extra whitespace (not showing up well in the comments here, but try for yourself).
Any idea on how to translate it without that extra whitespace?

Comment: @gammapoint Yes, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Whitespace it now gone, but so is some of the content. Output is now: `<body><h1>A header</h1><p><b>before</b></p><ul><li>test element</li>
<li>test element2
<b>something else</b></li></ul><p> Following <i>stuff</i></p></body>`. The "Just a normal paragraph" part was removed.

Comment: @gammapoint My apologies, it turns out the extra "spaces" was due to the presence of newlines (`\n`), which I updated my solution to filter out, and I am now getting the correct solution on my end.

Comment: Thank you Ajax, that seems to work now. Really appreciate all your help on this!